# ZFS on Linux: clear receive_resume_token pointing to a no longer existing snapshot

Tags: linux, debian, zfs, zfsonlinux, raspbian

I am using syncoid from [sanoid project](https://github.com/jimsalterjrs/sanoid) to create copies of ZFS filesystems on a different machine in my test environment (a couple of Raspberry Pi)

I messed up with a snapshot on origin machine: one server panicked during a snapshot transfer and later I deleted the snapshot that was being transferred.

I manually created a new snapshot and successfully restored it on target.

Now, when I run syncoid on target server using:

```
 ${SYNCOID} --sshkey="${SSH_KEY}" root@${REMOTE_SERVER}:${SRC_POOL}/${SAMPLE_FILESYSTEM} ${DEST_POOL}
```

it complains it cannot resume a send/receive transaction

During normal operations, syncoid retrieves the receive_resume_token on target machine:

```
/usr/local/sbin/zfs get -H receive_resume_token 'destpool/samplefs'
```

If it finds one, it tries to retrieve the snapshot corresponding to that token on source machine:

```
ssh sourceserver zfs send -t (token stored in receive_resume_token retrieved above) | (network stuff...) | zfs receive -s -F 'destpool/samplefs'

cannot resume send: 'sourcepool/samplefs@samplesnap' used in the initial send no longer exists
```

The only way to have it working is adding the "--no-resume" flag to syncoid command. This is not what i want, since some filesystems are very large and systems crashes are likely in this invironment.

I tried to clear that token by running:

```
 zfs recv -A 'srcpool/samplefs'
```

on source machine, and:

```
 zfs recv -A 'destpool/samplefs'
```

on target machine, i get:

```
srcpool/samplefs does not have any resumable receive state to abort
```

(on target machine it is destpool/samplefs)

**Question is: Is there a way to clear the receive_resume_token attribute on target filesystem?**

*Please note that this problem is only present with ONE filesystem. There are many other working transfers on both machines in both directions using the same commands set.*

Answer (score 1):

If `zfs recv -A` does not help, you can try destroying (or renaming) the destination dataset and resynching it.

Please also note the using `syncoid` with the `--no-resume` option should not be a problem: even on large datasets, incremental updates are generally quite small and do not benefit from resume support (which, on contrary, can be useful for the first, full sync).

Comment: There are cases when datasets and/or deltas are very large. The chance to resume would be helpful. The question is about how to regain the availability of the resume feature in a situation as described. Your answer bypasses the problem in two ways: either by starting from scratch (not viable if the filesystem is large enough to require longer than available time) or by using --no-resume (not viable if deltas are  large enough to require longer than available time)